# How to clear float for the inner divs using the psuedo classes? I have wrote the css but still its not working

Tags: html, css

```css
.black::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.black {
  background-color: #000000;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: 100px;
}
.orange {
  background-color: #ffa500;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="orange"></div>
</div>
```

How to clear float for the inner divs using the psuedo classes? I have wrote the css but still its not working.

Comment: you can use `clear` property. :D

Comment: you can use :after and :before psuedo classes to the inner divs.

Comment: I can do that by clear prop, but i wanted it by pseudo class for the orange named class

Comment: Please edit your CSS into your question. You probably want to add the `:after` pseudo element to `.main` instead of `.black`.

Comment: Just a note: IE8 does not support syntax with double-colons i.e. `::before`, only single-colons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. Pseudo-elements are placed inside parent elements so can't clear floats before they get displayed.

For example this rule will provide the following result:

```
.black::after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

[image]

And this rule the following:

```
.orange::before {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
```

[image]

Both can't clear the float before element appear. In your case you have to add `clear` property in the `.orange` div.

```css
.black {
  background-color: #000000;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: 100px;
}
.orange {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #ffa500;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="black"></div>
  <div class="orange"></div>
</div>
```